# How we Fire more than one event on same control in MVVM (WPF)

Tags: mvvm

I am creating WPF application using MVVM pattern. I want to fire more than one event on same control. For example: If i have placed one button. i want to fire Mouse_Up event as well as Loaded event on same button. Please Help me thanks in advance.